# Select where model property contains all in list of key value pairs

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have the following class

```
public class Account
{
    IEnumerable<AccountData> Data { get; set; }
}
```

where AccountData is

```
public class AccountData
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual AccountTag AccountTag { get; set; }
    public virtual string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and where Account Tag is

```
public class AccountTag
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to return all accounts where the Data field is in a list of key value pairs . long is the AccountTag.Id, and the AccountData.Value contains the string

Here is what I have so far, but this is performed on the web server and there could be thousands of accounts returned so I am looking for a linq to sql version.

```
public IEnumerable<Account> FindByCompanyDataTags(long companyId, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<long, string>> tags)
{
    var tempAccounts = (from acc in this.Data where acc.Company.Id == companyId orderby acc.Name select acc);
    IList<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

    foreach (var account in tempAccounts)
    {
       var matches = true;
       foreach (var t in tags)
       {
          if (account.Data.Any(x => x.AccountTag.Id == t.Key && x.Value.Contains(t.Value)))
          {
            continue;
          }

          matches = false;
          break;
        }

        if (matches)
        {
          accounts.Add(account);
        }
      }

      return accounts;
}
```

If I use resharper to convert this into a linq expression I get the following

```
public IEnumerable<Account> FindByCompanyDataTags(long companyId, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<long, string>> tags)
{
  var tempAccounts = (from acc in this.Data where acc.Company.Id == companyId orderby acc.Name select acc);
  IList<Account> accounts = (from account in tempAccounts let matches = tags.All(t => account.Data.Any(x => x.AccountTag.Id == t.Key && x.Value.Contains(t.Value))) where matches select account).ToList();

  return accounts;
}
```

But when I run this I get a method not supported exception.

This is really confusing me, any suggestions?

Comment: Is this Linq-to-NHibernate, or Linq-to-SQL?

Comment: Good catch, it's linq to nhibernate

Comment: Yes, NH LINQ provider is still not fully implemented (although I am not sure even EF handles complex queries that well). If you can use HQL, you would get better results. That's why we nevertheless use the Repository pattern with NH, so that we can easily "hand craft" some specific operations if needed. When you expose your data as IQueryable, you must have faith that LINQ to NHibernate will be able to translate all of your queries properly (and it doesn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because in first case you prepare query to db during `foreach` execution here

```
foreach (var account in tempAccounts)
{....}
```

You get collection of `Account` objects and working with them on client side in memory (other words, you're using Linq to objects)

In the second case you're trying execute Linq to Sql query but provider cannot translate working with your `KeyValuePair` objects into sql query, therefore it raise exception said about that.

**UPDATE**

Try to use `IQueryable` and build your query thorugh consequently applying `Where` clause:

```
IQueryable<Account> tempAccountsWithWhere = tempAccounts;
foreach (var tag in tags)
{
    tempAccountsWithWhere = tempAccountsWithWhere.Where(
        a => a.Data.Any(
            ad => ad.AccountTag.Id == tag.Key && ad.Value.Contains(tag.Value)));
}
IList<Account> accounts = tempAccountsWithWhere.ToList();
```

Comment: Agreed, the first case is not the best, hence why I want to use the second scenario. Is there an alternative to it that won't throw an exception which offers better performance?